# Is it possible to use git to find out what computer a file was made on?

Tags: git, computer-forensics

Is it possible to use git to find out what computer a file was made on? If you have a code repo, is it possible to examine the files and see on what computer they were made and by what username? For instance, were they created on mac or linux?

Comment: Most likely not.  What is it you need to know.

Comment: added example for yo

Comment: At best you can find out which commit introduced file.

Comment: Why do you need to know this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I do not believe that is possible. A Git repo is just a group of commits. From a great DZone article ([Git Behind the Curtain: What Happens When You Commit, Branch, and Merge](https://dzone.com/articles/git-behind-the-curtain-what-happens-when-you-commi)):

> Each commit contains three pieces of information: metadata about the
>   commit (who made it, when it happened, and the message), a list of
>   parent commits (which is empty for the first commit but has at least
>   one entry for every other commit), and a reference to the “tree”
>   object holding the root of the project directory.

Even at that, the "who" part comes from your Git config -- `user.name` & `user.email`.

Comment: Does that mean that the files themselves (for instance README.txt) does not contain any info on who created it and on what computer?

Comment: The files only contain whatever data they have, Git does not add anything extra. A plain text file will not have any extra information about the computer. Some other file formats (like MS Office files) include metadata that may point to who created it.